# twitter bootstrap fill height with Stashy sidebar flyout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm tryng t use the [Stashy Flyout](http://stashy.azurewebsites.net/flyout) component to have a flyout side bar. So far everything works fine except one small problem in the css. The height on the DIV content in the body is not resizing to 100% of the height. I have debugged in chrome, and up to the body tag, i get full height, after the "st-flyout" class tag, the height follows the content, and not the body.

here is some code in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/picopayne/zrBGw/1085/)!

in the fiddle is a simulation of my problem, I expect the whole result page to be colored with any of the corresponding id color, s1,s2..s5.. but all of these div have the same height of the s5 or the content.

```
    <div class="st-sticky-wrap">
    <div id="s1" class="st-flyout">
        <div id="s2" class="st-flyout-container">
            <div id="s3" class="st-flyout-main">
                <div id="s4" class="row">
                    <div id="s5">
                        <div class="container fill">
                            <div class="page-header">
                                 <h1>Hello World<small>small world</small></h1>

                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-6"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



.fill {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#s1 {
    background:green;
}
#s2 {
    background:blue;
}
#s3 {
    background:red;
}
#s4 {
    background:black;
}
#s5 {
    background:yellow;
}
```

please help... I need s1 to be the same height of the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked your jsfiddle post 
here are the thing you need to change 
remove height for  .st-sticky-wrap "height: auto !important;"- delete this and add following styles 
its works seeing green color background all over the page

```
    html,body
    {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        padding:0px;
        margin: 0px;
    }
    .fill {
        min-height: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .st-sticky-wrap
    {
        height: 100%;
    }
    #s1 {
        background:green;
        height: 100%;

    }
    #s2 {
        background:blue;
    }
    #s3 {
        background:red;
    }
    #s4 {
        background:black;
    }
    #s5 {
        background:yellow;
    }
```

```
URL jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/qa9243d8/
```

Cheers

Comment: great. you pointed me in the right direction. the problem i face when put into my project, i have to set the Height:100% in each of the nested DIV element. why is this so? can't it inherit from the parent DIV?

Comment: basically my final goal is to set the s5 the whole height, means yellow all over the page. so i need to set each parent div untill s5 with height 100%!?

Comment: height cannot inherited by the parents. you have to mention manually for all the containers. thumbs up